gtk4 can't see object from Golang
I try to create some GUI for golang. My choose was gtk4 library with https://github.com/diamondburned/gotk4 packege.
I stucked on transfer Go Objects to gtk4 template.
bond.ui
<object class="GtkScrolledWindow">
            <property name="height-request">400</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkColumnView">
                <property name="model">
                  <object class="GtkSingleSelection" id="selection_model"/>
                </property>
                <property name="tab-behavior">cell</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkColumnViewColumn" id="figi_column">
                    <property name="expand">True</property>
                    <property name="factory">
                      <object class="GtkBuilderListItemFactory">
                        <property name="bytes"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <template class="GtkColumnViewCell">
    <property name="child">
      <object class="GtkLabel">
        <property name="xalign">0</property>
        <binding name="label">
          <lookup name="name" type="GObject">
            <lookup name="item">GtkColumnViewCell</lookup>
          </lookup>
        </binding>
      </object>
    </property>
  </template>
</interface>]]></property>
                      </object>
                    </property>
                    <property name="title">FIGI</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>

Go code
import (
    _ "embed"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/diamondburned/gotk4/pkg/core/gioutil"
    "github.com/diamondburned/gotk4/pkg/core/glib"
    "github.com/diamondburned/gotk4/pkg/gtk/v4"
    "log"
)

//go:embed bond.ui
var uiXML string

type BondItem struct {
    figi string
    name string
}

var BondsData = gioutil.NewListModel[BondItem]()

func main() {
app := gtk.NewApplication("anton_helper.antonkisselev", gio.ApplicationFlagsNone)

    builder := gtk.NewBuilderFromString(uiXML)
    window := builder.GetObject("bond_window").Cast().(*gtk.Window)

    table := builder.GetObject("selection_model").Cast().(*gtk.SingleSelection)

    BondsData.Append(BondItem{
        figi: "erfegre",
        name: "name1",
    })
    BondsData.Append(BondItem{
        figi: "eefyyyyegre",
        name: "name2",
    })
    table.SetModel(BondsData)

    app.AddWindow(window)
    window.SetVisible(true)
}

the result is column with 2 emptry rows
and error like this :
2024/12/23 23:04:09 ERROR Error building template for list item: .:0:0: Type `GObject` does not have a property name `name` priority=4 code_file=../../../gtk/gtkbuilderlistitemfactory.c code_line=110 code_func=gtk_builder_list_item_factory_setup glib_domain=Gtk


So why gtk4 dont see go object with all fields?
What i am doing wrong

It would be good if you provided a Minimal, Reproducible
Example instead of code with .... and no imports.

Updated. I thought this is unnessesary
